# event delegation click on thumbnails not showing main image

Tags: javascript, html, event-delegation

I trying to create thumbnails which when clicked show up in a main image. I've tested the code and all seems to be in order however the main images are not showing when thumbsnails are clicked. There's a 404 error message showing in chrome. I know the file pathways are correct because when I remove the `preventDefault()` the link displays the file containing the image ?

I have played around with this for some time now. Is there an error in the code I'm not seeing or some action I haven't accounted for. I'm new to javascript.

```
    <img id="viewer" src="images/motorbike-girl.jpg" width='450px' />
    <div id='thumbs'>
       <a href='images/chicks.jpg'><img src='images/chicks-thumb.jpg'/></a>
       <a href='images/motorbike-girl.jpg'><img src='images/motorbike-girl-thumb.jpg'/></a>
       <a href='images/yamaha.jpg'><img src='images/yamaha-thumb.PNG' /></a>
    </div>

 var thumbs = document.getElementById('thumbs');
 var img = document.getElementById('viewer');

 thumbs.onclick = function(event) {

   var target = event.target;

   while(target != thumbs) {

    if(target.nodeName == 'A') {
      img.src = this.href;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
     target = target.parentNode;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
img.src = this.href;
```

should be:

```
img.src = target.href;
```

You should also `break` out of the loop once you find the `A` node and set the image source.

Answer (score 1):

Use use:

```
img.src = this.href;
```

Should use:

```
img.src = target.href;
```